# Distance between a point and several locations

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am developing an application that shows the distance between the user and multiple locations (such as foursquare in the image below) on android, I am using eclipse and would like to know how to calculate the distance between various points. Thank you!

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsWmO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to get this done, here's an option.

You could use the [distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) method. If you want more than one distance, simply use a loop to repeat it until you've calculated the distances between all the Locations you have at hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Maps, you can use a Distance Matrix
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

Comment: Thanks, but I need to put the distance of each point in a position in the list ... as in the image of the foursquare

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes that's what distance matrix gives you

Answer (score 0):

Here I am providing you some sample code for Distance calculation. I have done like this in my project. Here distanceTo() method will return you the distance in double.

```
private Location currentLocation, distanceLocation;
double distance = 0;

//set your current location 
currentLocation.setLatitude(currentLat);
currentLocation.setLongitude(currentLong);

//set your destination location
distanceLocation = new Location("");
distanceLocation.setLatitude(destinatioLat);
distanceLocation.setLongitude(destinationLong);

distance = currentLocation.distanceTo(distanceLocation)/1000;
```

Same for more then one location you can use Array for storing distance. Its on you how you want to use it as per your requirement.

Hope this will help you.