# Distance between two location in Android map

Tags: android, android-mapview

How to calculate distance between 2 location in android map & output must display in textview or any ?

Comment: possible duplicate, check these SO posts, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981916/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitu    and    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877455/distance-between-a-point-and-several-locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those people like me, who are learning now/late. Have made use of the code written by @NaserShaikh below.
Here you go a working code to get driving distance on google map when u have lat,long of two points!! distance is in miles !
There are better way to parse the JSON response pls look for it. 
Havent tested it for extremes when there is a ocean btw and other stuffs. Hope it helps.

```
package havefun;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

class Distance {
    private Double dist;
    public Distance() {
        dist = (double) -1;

    }

    private Double getDistance(){
        StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();

              HttpPost  httpPost = new HttpPost("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=<src_lat>,<src_long>&destination=<dst_lat>,<dst_long>&sensor=false&mode=driving");

              CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                try {

                 CloseableHttpResponse HttpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    InputStream in = HttpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    int ch = 0;
                    while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                        jsonString.append((char) ch);
                    }
                    in.close();


                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString.toString());
                    //System.out.println(jsonObject);
                    //System.out.println("========================");
                    //System.out.println(jsonObject.get("status"));
                    if (jsonObject.get("status").toString().equals("OK") == false) {
                        System.err.println("Error");
                        return dist;
                    }

                    String distance = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("distance").getString("text");

                    System.out.println(distance);

                    String temp[] = distance.split(" ");
                    System.out.println(temp[1]);
                    System.out.println(temp[0]);

                    dist = Double.parseDouble(temp[0]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return dist;

        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Distance d = new Distance();
            Double dist = d.getDistance();
            System.out.println("Distance ="+dist);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i think you need googleapi for that, i had use such service before..
you can get distance from your current location to destination.

simply uee following url:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false&mode=driving

here, origin=%f,%f = origin=latitude,longitude
destination=%f,%f = destination=latitude,longitude

google response:

```
{

    "routes": [
        {
            "bounds": {
                "northeast": { … },
                "southwest": { … }
            },
            "copyrights": "Map data ©2012 Inav/Geosistemas SRL",
            "legs": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "1 m",
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "duration": { … },
                    "end_address": "Formosa Province, Argentina",
                    "end_location": { … },
                    "start_address": "Formosa Province, Argentina",
                    "start_location": { … },
                    "steps": [ … ],
                    "via_waypoint": [ ]
                }
            ],
            "overview_polyline": { … },
            "summary": "RP 3",
            "warnings": [ ],
            "waypoint_order": [ ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"

}
```

Above u can see

```
"distance": {
                            "text": "1 m",
                            "value": 0
                        },
```

there is your distance:

code may look like this:

```
private void getDistance(){
StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();

        httpPost = new HttpPost("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=<latitude>,<longitude>&destination=<latitude>,<longitude>&sensor=false&mode=driving");


        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            InputStream in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            int ch = 0;
            while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                jsonString.append((char) ch);
            }
            in.close();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(""legs");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String text = jObj.getString("text");
                String value = jObj.getString("value");//value is ur distance
            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

hope it help.

Comment: can give d example if u have.

Comment: its really simple. if you know the JSON parsing. just hit above URL with your source and destination location. and in response google will give u JSON object which has a distance between two location.

Answer (score 2):

```
textView.setText(""+location1.distanceTo(location2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Calculate the distance between 2 points based on their GeoPoint coordinates. <br>
 * Return the value in Km or miles based on the unit input
 * @param gp1 (GeoPoint): First point.
 * @param gp2 (GeoPoint): Second point.
 * @param unit (char): Unit of measurement: 'm' for miles and 'k' for Km.
 * @return (double): The distance in miles or Km.
 */
public static double getDistance(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2, char unit)
{
    //Convert from degrees to radians
    final double d2r = Math.PI / 180.0;

    //Change lat and lon from GeoPoint E6 format
    final double lat1 = gp1.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
    final double lat2 = gp2.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
    final double lon1 = gp1.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
    final double lon2 = gp2.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;

    //The difference between latitudes and longitudes
    double dLat = Math.abs(lat1 - lat2) * d2r;
    double dLon = Math.abs(lon1 - lon2) * d2r;

    double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2.0), 2) 
            + Math.cos(lat1 * d2r) * Math.cos(lat2 * d2r)
            * Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon / 2.0), 2);

    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

    //Return the distance
    return (unit == 'm' ? 3956 : 6367) * c;
} //End getDistance()


TextView textView.setText("" + getDistance(gp1, gp2, 'k'));
```