# Getting nearest bus stations from Google Map inside Android Application

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-places-api

I am working on an Android application in which I need to achieve the following goals.

1. Get the current position(co-ordinates) of the device - Done
2. Search within a given radius centering the device position for the nearest bus stations and List them.

I need help on the second thing. Is there any way to get the Nearest bus stations from the Google Map inside an android application? Can I use Google Places API to achieve this?(the official page says that it's still experimental). If yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214525/distance-between-two-location-in-android-map/12214695#12214695

Comment: Thanks for that, But actually I am not planning to use Maps, just get the place tags using GPlaces API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could successfully achieve these by referring [Davy's Tech Blog Article](http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html) and the code sample provided in [Github](https://github.com/ddewaele/GooglePlacesApi)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do a reverse geocoding on your coordinates:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

then do a search like this:

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=transit stop near the_address_obtain_with_reverse_geocoding&output=json

Comment: I could find the exact solution from somewhere else, this was somehow close to that solution, thanks.

Comment: Could you post your answer here? I am still having trouble on getting the bus stations