# Download bus station coordinates google maps

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

Is there any posibility to download programmatically bus station coordinates from google maps or here maps?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to download all the Bus stop information Google has in one big download. However, look at a previous post that describes two alternative ways:

[Getting nearest bus stations from Google Map inside Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401510/getting-nearest-bus-stations-from-google-map-inside-android-application)

If you don’t particularly want to use Google places API, look at the second link for Overpass, it was really quick to get a list from there. http://overpass-turbo.eu/