# How to calculate active user in Mobile App Analytics?

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, active-users

How to calculate active user or returning user or inActive user in mobile app google analytical appview ?

I have search lots of things.but no more accurate answer as per my confusion.

1. If user has intalled the app once in his device and after install user has never launched our app.
2. If user has installed our app and launch it daily, but user has not any transaction.

So Is this user active or inactive?

Comment: Did you read https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214525/distance-between-two-location-in-android-map check this for Distance between geopoints

Comment: I had problem with  Analytics and firebase First open / active user count. I created two test project( one with just firebase, one with firebase and analytics tracker) and run it on 4 phones. unfortunately only active users was 1 ( the only phone with google account on it) and in second app there is just two active user. I realy disappointed  from google.

Comment: @Kenji all phone have different google account?

Comment: yes. I find out all of this in this question.https://stackoverflow.com/q/45388640/1498586      I will update answer soon as data came in Analytics and firebase.

Answer (score 1):

*If user has intalled the app once in his device and after install user has never launched our app.* **This user will never show up in Google Analytics, so not an Active user**

(this isn't a user for Google Analytics until the app is opened and a screen view is sent)

*If user has installed our app and launch it daily, but user has not any transaction.* **This user will be a Returning User as well as an Active User**

For a user to appear in any of the Google Analytics report, at least one event / appview has to be sent to Google Analytics

---

**New User**

When the first Google Analytics send is performed, the SDK generates the `client_id` and sends it over to Google Analytics

**Returning User**

Every data being sent to Google Analyics is accompanied by `client_id`, a successful lookup to the previous client_id set would allow Google Analytics to tag as the user as returning user.

**Active User**

Google Analytics recieving data with the same client_id for several # of days is classified as a `X` days, where `X` is the continous time interavl the user has been sedning the event data.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of active and inactive users is based on a time frame. ie. Daily, Weekly, Monthly, etc.

1. If someone installed the app and never opened it, they are not counted as an active user because GA requires the app to be opened to send any data.
2. Activity is based on sessions so if a user opens the app every day they are considered a daily active user.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6171863?hl=en